# How can I create a searchable document repository for Azure application?

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc, azure, full-text-search, azure-sql-database

We have a client requirement to upload documents (Word Doc and possibly PDF) to our Azure hosted application and have full text search on the document.

My understanding is that SQL  Azure doesn't support full text indexing so I can't just store them in the DB.

Has anyone done anything similar? If so how? Are there any Nuget packages or things I can install into the Azure role etc when I create it? Is blob storage serachable/indexable?

Any ideas?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you are doing this now and you are using Azure. It is best to combine this with [Azure Search Service](https://azure.microsoft.com/en-gb/services/search/). It has stacks of features and you can add text and meta data to allow fast searching. It has various options options indexing blob etc [blob indexing](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/search/search-howto-indexing-azure-blob-storage)

Answer (score 3):

I would suggest using Lucene.NET along with your data.  Take a look at:

http://code.msdn.microsoft.com/windowsazure/Azure-Library-for-83562538

Comment: This is the best solution available today. And to answer the other question, blob storage is not searchable/indexable. You'll need to do this yourself. Ex: before saving a document, index the contents using Lucene.NET

Comment: Sounds great. Could it also allow me to search on metadata associated with the blob? We want to associate documents with a database record so either I need to do that with metadata and store an ID etc or do it via the structure of the "directory path"

Comment: Take a look at this, you can index any of the metadata you like: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/magazine/hh335069.aspx